# Apache camel, a way to "join" 2 routes

Tags: java, csv, spring-boot, apache-camel

So long story short. At work we have our own ETL tool for integrations. However this is proving tedious and we are considering moving to Apache Camel or Spring Integration. So far so good however. In our current tool we have to option to "join" 2 input sources into one.

Here is an example with 2 files (using csv format)

File 1: 
--------
Id;Name
1;Jon
2;Jane

File 2:
--------
Id;Pet
1;Dog
2;Cat
3;Mouse

Then in our ETL tool we have a processor where we can join the 2 files into one. Very much like an SQL join where we specify what to join with and what output fields should come out in the resulting file. In this example we join on the field **Id** which exists in both files. And specify we want all the data from both files. Then the outcome would be like this:

Resulting File:
------------------
Id;Name;Pet
1;Jon;Dog
2;Jane;Cat

In camel this would be achieved by creating 2 routes and aggregating those am 
I right? Regardless could someone please show me an example of how to do this using Java DSL?

BR
Johan

Comment: I would do something like a dataframe join in R or Python Pandas. There, loading CSVs and joining them is really quite trivial.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to aggregate CSV lines with Apache Camel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353549/how-to-aggregate-csv-lines-with-apache-camel)

Comment: I think you need to elaborate your question. Based on input/output I would expect you want to group the data of both files in one message. But later you write the opposite (that you do not want to group the data).

Comment: Sorry for being confusing, updated the question, hopefully less confusing now.

Comment: Updated topic to be about joining 2 routes, from what I can read that seams to be the equivalent of what i want to do in camel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, what i needed to create 2 routes and then use pollEnrich on the second route.